# Getting json data into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently using jquery and javascript to get json data, which I would like to add to a list.
The raw data received from it's source looks like this;

```
null({"groups": "Blacksheep,Family,Voice,Technical,Band"})
```

with a bit of code my input comes out as

```
Blacksheep,Family,Voice,Technical,Band
```

My code takes these values and puts them though a for loop, looping once for each entry. it then takes that entry's name and puts it into a `<li>` field on my html document inside of a `<ul>` tag named `people`.

```
for (i=0 ; i < input.length ; i++){
    console.log(input);
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML += "<li>" + input[i] + "</li>";
}
```

I tried to turn it into an array but adding a '[' on each side, but obviously it isn't so easy. at the moment it takes the json entry and lists each letter instead of word.

is there a way to separate each word from json? or a way to interpret it as an array?

Comment: Did you try this: `{"groups": ["Blacksheep","Family","Voice","Technical","Band"]}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can split the var

```
"Blacksheep,Family,Voice,Technical,Band".split(',');
```

this returning a string of array..

Answer (score 3):

The data is a string. you can use `.split(delimiter)` to split the words.

```
//split by ",". now input is an array
input = input.split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the string and use .split to convert it to an Array

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. As all the answer mention split the string.

```
var arr = "Blacksheep,Family,Voice,Technical,Band";
var input = arr.split(",");

for (i=0 ; i < input.length ; i++){
    console.log(input);
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML += "<li>" + input[i] + "</li>";
}
```